# osx switch between two nsviews

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I would like to switch between two `NSView` controls upon pressing the button. Basically, i have .xib file which contains `NSWindow` control. Window contains two subviews and few buttons. I have dragged `NSViewController` in object list and one more `NSView` in xib.
`NSViewController` has reference to view from `NSWindow` and view that is floating in xib file.

Question is, how can i switch between nsview1 and nsview2 in `NSWindow` upon button press? Is this the right way to do it ?

[image: sketch]

Comment: One way could be to use tab view and hide tabs, and then switch between tabs...

Answer (score 8):

Define a NSView outlet for the placeholder of where the swappable view is as well as a property for keeping a reference to the current view controller in use.

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSView* mainView;
@property (strong) NSViewController* currentViewController;
```

I use a generic method for the view swapping (using autolayout to make view take up entire placeholder view).

```
-(void)setMainViewTo:(NSViewController *)controller
{
    //Remove existing subviews
    while ([[self.mainView subviews] count] > 0)
    {
        [self.mainView.subviews[0] removeFromSuperview];
    }
    NSView * view = [controller view];
    [view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.mainView addSubview:view];

    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view);   

    [self.mainView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view]|"
                                                                 options:0
                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                   views:viewsDictionary]];

    [self.mainView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view]|"
                                                                 options:0
                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                   views:viewsDictionary]];
    self.currentViewController = controller;
}
```

Now you can define IBOutlets to instantiate and swap your view controllers

```
-(IBAction)showView1:(id)sender
{
    View1Controller * controller = [[View1Controller alloc]init];
    [self setMainViewTo:controller];
}
-(IBAction)showView2:(id)sender
{
    View2Controller * controller = [[View2Controller alloc]init];
    [self setMainViewTo:controller];
}
```